# Stored Procedure to Return Multiple Values based on different simultaneous Input conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a stored procedure that gets a person's name, matches the name with values in a table and return the correct format via output variable. If the name is not in the table/database the stored procedure simply output the original entry. This part works fine.

Now I want to do both first and last names together in the same stored procedure; example:

1. If first name has a match, output matched - *output variable*
2. If Last name has a match send out a match - *output variable*
3. If both names match send out the match for both BUT via different output variable.

I am having a hard time because I am not sure how to process both names, and get both or one, or the other:

I could do separate Procedures but that would not be wise.

***Table Name Is: (StringFormat)***

[image]

***Stored Procedure:***

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspFormat]

@FName VARCHAR(30),
@FNameMatchedValue VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT

AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ValueMatched VARCHAR(30)

SELECT @ValueMatched =  StringValue
FROM StringFormat WHERE MatchedValue = @FName;

IF @ValueMatched IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
SET
@FNameMatchedValue = @ValueMatched
END

RETURN 0

END
```

Thanks for looking:

***UPDATE: Please Review My Solution:***

Okay after posting I went back and modified the code which I had done wrong before:
It is working but returning unique values even when one name is a match. However I am not sure this is the best way to do it:

Another Change: I simply used two viriables to get the matched rather then one:

`@FirstNameMatched` and `@LastNameMatched`

***Code after modification:***

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspFormat]

@FName VARCHAR(30),
@LName VARCHAR(30),
@FNameMatchedValue VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT,
@LNameMatchedValue VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT

AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @FirstNameMatched VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @LastNameMatched VARCHAR(30)

SELECT @FirstNameMatched =  StringValue
FROM StringFormat WHERE MatchedValue = @FName;

IF @FirstNameMatched IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
SET
@FNameMatchedValue = @FirstNameMatched
END

ELSE
BEGIN
SET @FNameMatchedValue = @FName
END

BEGIN 
SELECT @LastNameMatched =  StringValue
FROM StringFormat WHERE MatchedValue = @LName;

IF @LastNameMatched IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
SET
@LNameMatchedValue = @LastNameMatched
END

ELSE
BEGIN
SET @LNameMatchedValue = @LName
END
END

RETURN 0

END
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use `select @FNameMatchedValue = StringValue from StringFormat where MatchedValue = @FName; select @LNameMatchedValue = StringValue from StringFormat where MatchedValue = @LName;` and call it a day?  Of course, you seem to know that there can never be more than one matching row.

Comment: I did try it that way before and got the same value for both names if one name matched. Even the above code is returning the same value for both. Maybe I need different matched variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspFormat]

@FName VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT,
@LName VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT,
@FNameBothMatched VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT,
@LNameBothMatched VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT

AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @FnameMatched VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @LnameMatched VARCHAR(30)

SELECT TOP 1 @FnameMatched =  StringValue
FROM StringFormat WHERE MatchedValue = @FName;

SELECT TOP 1 @LnameMatched =  StringValue
FROM StringFormat WHERE MatchedValue = @LName;

IF (@FnameMatched IS NOT NULL) and (@LnameMatched IS NOT NULL)

   BEGIN
     SET @FNameBothMatched = @FnameMatched
     SET @LNameBothMatched = @LnameMatched
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
     IF (@FnameMatched IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
           SET @Fname = @FnameMatched
        END
     IF (@LnameMatched IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
           SET @Lname = @LnameMatched
        END
   END


RETURN 0

END
```

---

Admittedly I did not test this but what I am trying to do here following your own requirements are this:

1. if both Lastname and Firstname has matched then it would go both to @FNameBothMached and @LNameBothMatched
2. if only Firstname has matched then it would change the passed @Fname otherwise @Fname passed value will remain as it is
3. if only Lastname has matched then it would change the passed @Lname otherwise @Lname passed value will remain as it is

---

**Scenarios**:

**Scenario 1**: Fistname has match but Lastname has no match

**Passed Value**

Firstname : Macdonald   (has match)

Lastname  : Obrian  (has no match)

**Result Scenario 1**

Firstname : Mac Donald

Lastname : Obrian

**Scenario 2**: Fistname has no match but Lastname has match

**Passed Value**

Firstname : McDonald   (has no match)

Lastname  : Obrien  (has match)

**Result Scenario 2**

Firstname : McDonald

Lastname : O'brien

**Scenario 3**: Fistname has no match and Lastname has no match as well

**Passed Value**

Firstname : McDonald   (has no match)

Lastname  : Obrian  (has no match)

**Result Scenario 3**

Firstname : McDonald

Lastname : Obrian

**Scenario 4**: Both Fistname and Lastname has match

**Passed Value**

Firstname : Macdonald   (has match)

Lastname  : Obrien  (has match)

**Result Scenario 4**

Firstname : MacDonald

Lastname : O'brien

Comment: So in my version, if a name is not there the output returns the input value as entered. When I removed the ELSE in my code version, I got a null output if a name was not matched. I like your version and it looks and reads better, just wondering if it returns null. Regardless it's a great place for me to start. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome @UnaverageGuy. Kindly just try my version if it works. And yes in your case if you removed the ELSE it will give you a NULL. In my case I have four OUTPUT parameters, if both Lastname and Firstname then 3rd and 4th is for if both Lastname and Firstname has matched otherwise the 1st and 2nd parameters will be used. So, if Firstname has matched then '@Fname' will return the match value otherwise the original passed value remains. Or if Lastname has matched '@Lname' will return the matched value otherwise the original passed value for lastname will return.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you are putting in here especially on a Saturday: I wont need four output because I have to use two input in C# to input the data from a form. However, this is a jump start and learning avenue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a better way.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspFormat]
@FName VARCHAR(30),
@LName VARCHAR(30)
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

select
(select StringValue FROM StringFormat WHERE MatchedValue = @FName) as FNameMatchedValue,

(select StringValue FROM StringFormat WHERE MatchedValue = @LName) as LNameMatchedValue

RETURN 0

END
```

Above way return a DataTable to you. but if You want the output using output type variable then there also a better solution exists

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspFormat]
@FName VARCHAR(30),
@LName VARCHAR(30),
@FNameMatchedValue VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT,
@LNameMatchedValue VARCHAR(30) OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON


select @FNameMatchedValue=StringValue FROM StringFormat WHERE MatchedValue = @FName

select @LNameMatchedValue=StringValue FROM StringFormat WHERE MatchedValue = @LName

RETURN 0

END
```